# c++ linking boost library under ubuntu with cmake: undefined reference to `boost::iostreams::zlib::okay'

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, gzip

I have problems with `boost::iostreams`. I want to use them in only one function.
The only problem is with this line:

```
in.push(boost::iostreams::gzip_decompressor());
```

Boost is used in other parts of the program without any problems or compile errors.
However If I use this line I get the compile error:

```
undefined reference to `boost::iostreams::zlib::okay'
```

It is included like this:

```
#include <boost/iostreams/filter/gzip.hpp>
```

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
add_library(backend
    ... some files
)

find_package(Boost COMPONENTS system REQUIRED)
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(backend ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

Comment: you should add zlib to the linker inputs

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your `find_package` call for Boost is incomplete.

All non-header-only libraries from Boost which you use need to be listed explicitly for `${Boost_LIBRARIES}` to be populated correctly. It is easy to lose track of which parts of Boost are header-only and which are not, but linker errors like the one you encountered are always a clear hint.

```
find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS system iostreams)
```

Also note that you might have to pull in additional dependencies on Linux to get the compression to work, as [suggested in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24509382/c-linking-boost-library-under-ubuntu-with-cmake-undefined-reference-to-boost#comment37944728_24509382).

Comment: The day I will start to "get" the essentials of CMake... will be a nice day